# How to pass css for mobile device only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my web-application i want to pass difference css for mobile and computer. How can I do this?

For example:

If someone goto my site in computer then pass "screen.css" and when someone goto my site in mobile then pass difference css "screen1.css"

How can I do this? Please Help me
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out the mediaqueries. That's one possibility:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: if i use "screen" then it's pass in my mobile (samsung galaxy).that i don't want.

Comment: look deeper into the documentation. there is an example like this @media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) { ... }

Comment: Alternativly you can add a CSS-file with jQuery. Before you can check the browser (jQuery.browser) and if it's a mobile device load you CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In **Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mobile_device = 0;
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
if (mobile){ mobile_device = 1; }
</script>
```

In **HTML**:

```
<div id="show_this_when_mobile_device" style="display:none;">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile_css_path" type="text/css">
</div>
```

In **Javascript**:

```
if(mobile_dev == 1){$("#show_this_when_mobile_device").show();}
```